# Error message Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a null error on my DTO object at runtime:

[image]

I didn't understand because column is nullable:

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchParametersCompanyDTO
{
    public SearchParametersCompanyDTO();

    [DataMember]
    public CompanyColumnsEnumDTO? Column { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Term { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public enum CompanyColumnsEnumDTO
{
    [EnumMember]
    CompanyName = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    City = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    PostCode = 2,
}
```

It must be a conversion problem because null is accepted on Column:

```
        var dto = new SearchParametersCompanyDTO
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex,
            PageSize = defaultPageSize,
            Term = term,
            Column = null
        };
```

Any idea?

Comment: I know this comment is off-topic, but **bravo for asking a clear, detailed, answerable question**.  I see so many terrible questions on here, this is how it should be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to cast a null value to an enum type (rather than a nullable enum type). I'm guessing you actually want to change your cast to:

```
Column = (CompanyColumnsEnumDTO?) column
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is you're casting the value `column` into a non-nullable value `CompanyColumnsEnumDTO`.  Based on the exception it looks like `column` is `null` here and casting to a non-null appropriately throws an exception.  Did you mean to cast to `CompanyColumnsEnumDTO?` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to (CompanyColumnsEnumDTO?) instead of (CompanyColumnsEnumDTO)